# asp.net mobile web applications

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website

I'm working in a web mobile application to support a mimimal subset of operations for an existing website.
My base tools are, asp.net 4.0 with simple css to try to archive a more extensive range of devices.

My questions are:
 - I'm in a good direction? ... or ther's a better way to do it? (other kind of controls, etc..)
 - My device (mobile) is a Nokia e71 and i'm starting to see some glitches:
      - autopostback properties dont work
      - clientvalidationscripts dont work

Please give me some hints and advices. Thank u all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Mobile controls in ASP.NET, or just the regular ones? There is a separate set that are intended to support and adjust to various mobile devices somewhat better.

For a first-effort mobile site, I would look either at a well-established mobile framework (to be honest, I've never extensively used the ASP.NET Mobile Webforms controls), or to do something where I'm building my own HTML much more directly, to be sure to keep things mobile-safe.

That's one of the reasons I use ASP.NET MVC more myself, now... but that is a bit of a leap to make, and especially if it would just be for mobile use.

---

So anyway, if you are already using the ASP.NET Mobile controls, my answer is irrelevant!

Comment: Hi Andrew. I'm using only regular ones. As i can see System.Web.UI.MobileControls Namespace is obsolete in .net 4.0

Comment: Ahh; didn't know you were on 4.0. Go check out the ASP.net/mobile site and see what sort of goodness is there for you; http://www.asp.net/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

Always, regardless of the type of website, design for "Progressive enhancement".

In other words, get everything working using the minimum (no javascript, very simple CSS). Then progressively enhance it so that additional functionality is available to those with browsers that can support it.

Many ASP.NET controls have javascript behind them. Ensure that you design so that they continue to work without javascript, or use other controls that don't require javascript at all.

WRT your client validation - You should always validate on the server side as well. In that case the fact that on some devices the client validation isn't running makes no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any asp.net control on a mobile site, .net rendering by device usually screws things up.
Do not use .net server forms.
If you can use MVC
Simple javascripts should work most of the modern devices.
Ajax works too but don't use jQuery, write simple ajax post/get functons